# Box-shadow side-effect blur not smooth. inner square in shadow

Tags: html, css, box-shadow

I have a slider on my page to change the box-shadow values. At some high blurring values there is an unwanted box-like breaking the shadow, when it is supposed to be a smooth shadow all the way. Is there anyway to avoid this easily? Thanks for the help.
P. S.
I actually need it to work with 'inset' too.

[image]

```css
div
{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius: 100px;
 background-color:blue;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 169px 129px 300px -15px rgba(0,0,0,1);
 -moz-box-shadow: 169px 129px 300px -15px rgba(0,0,0,1);
 box-shadow: 169px 129px 300px -15px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: applying box-shadow to a circle results in this thing. try setting the border-radius after the shadow. *not tested*

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui: I don't believe that would make any difference at all to the rendering of the shape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For circular `box-shadows` the blur cannot go above the width & height of the element. The spread can though.

Since your element is `200px * 200px`, the maximum for the blur value is `200px`.

Have a look below at the example which doesn't go above `200px` and you will see that it creates the `box-shadow` as expected

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  box-shadow: 169px 129px 200px -15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

The spread value can alternatively go above the element width and height and therefore you can make bigger spreads.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  box-shadow: 169px 129px 0 250px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

You also didn't really need the prefixes since CSS3 Box-shadows are very well supported now. [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow)

You can read more about CSS Box shadows in the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

Comment: Thakns for your answer @Stewartside. But your code snippet still shows the same effect. (I'm using Chrom browser)

Comment: @IsraelGav read the explanation. Setting the blur bigger then the size of the element will al ways do this.

Comment: @IsraelGav It works perfectly on my chrome. What sort of effect were you expecting?

Comment: @Stewartside, these are the values you entered: "169px 129px 200px -15px". And that shows the same square lines in the shadow. while blur is not above the width. And furthermore, the same effect shows on rectangles.

Comment: I'm still not sure whether it's my browsers, or what else I'm missing. But the answer from @Persijn  is looking promising and very useful. I think I will concentrate on that for now.

Comment: OK, I've found out that it keeps the bad effect after your suggestion on lower resolution. To see this, you can zoom your browser in to enlarge the elements. you should see your code snippet doing the same problem.

Comment: I see what you mean now. This shouldnt be a problem if your viewport is set to 1 so that the browser doesn't zoom or render the elements at a different height/width

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go outside its dimensions on the shape to be blurred:

The code creates a copy of the circle then colours it black and uses the `filter:blur(length)`;

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.circle::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.circle::before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(50px);
  filter: blur(50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

You can also create inset shadows this way.

How it works:
 1. The initial shape is the shadow-color 
 2. Set overflow:hidden so nothing goes outside the shape.
 3. Put a shape on top
 4. Blur the shape on top

By doing this the shape under shines through creating the inner shadow effect

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.circle::before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: calc(100%);
  height: calc(100%);
  background-color: blue;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(20px);
  filter: blur(20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Persijn. Can you do this trick for an inset shadow too?

Comment: Added a inset shadow. But why not use the normal inset shadow one?